# masking multiple dynamic images in kineticjs using setClipFunc

Tags: kineticjs, masking, clipping

I'm trying to add a simple rectangular mask to cover multiple images, the container method 'setClipFunc' looks like a winner http://kineticjs.com/docs/symbols/Kinetic.Container.php#setClipFunc but confused as to how it works and why it is being passed a number 'deg' (presumably degrees?).  If anyone has a working example of 'setClipFunc' in action I'd be most grateful!

Answer (score 1):

```
        layer.setClipFunc(function (deg) {

        var context = deg.context;
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(5, 5);
        context.lineTo(34, 202);

        context.lineTo(2, 405);
        context.lineTo(212, 385);
        context.lineTo(425, 405);
        context.lineTo(400, 202);
        context.lineTo(415, 10);
        context.lineTo(212, 25);
        context.closePath();
    });
    layer.draw();
```

Comment: This answer is great and works however it's via creating paths directly on the native CanvasRenderingContext2D (deg.context).

All good if you want to use a native path but can you use Kinetic Shape objects within the clip function? ie. it would be good to be able to create multiple shapes to use as a clip or even text.

cheers